# next-auth pass custom value in signIn and use it in provider

Tags: identityserver4, next-auth, next.js13

I am implementing Identity server integration with the next application using next-auth. I have the below options file in the next-auth.

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import IdentityServer4Provider from "next-auth/providers/identity-server4";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    IdentityServer4Provider({
      id: "identity-server4",
      name: "IdentityServer4",
      issuer:  'Issuer',
      clientId: 'ClientId',
      clientSecret: 'ClientSecret',
      authorization: { 
        params: { scope: 'Scopes', login_resolution_policy : "Email" }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ trigger, session, token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
        token.idToken = account.id_token
      }
      console.log("Inside token trigger update", session, token) 

      if(trigger === "update") {
        token = { ...token, activeMemberId: session.activeMemberId };
        console.log("after update", session, token)
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token, user, trigger }) {     
      console.log("Inside session trigger update", session, token, user, trigger) 
      session = { ...session, idToken : token.idToken as string, accessToken : token.accessToken as string, activeMemberId: token.activeMemberId as string };
      return session
     }
  },
};
```

I am calling signIn() from client component like this:

```
 'use client'

import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Link from 'next/link';

function ClientComponent(){
    const { data: session, status, update } = useSession()
    
    const handleSignOut = async () => {
      console.log("signout clicked")
      signOut();
    };

    const handleSignIn = async () => {
      console.log("signin clicked")
      signIn("identity-server4", { callbackUrl: '/' }, { prompt: "login" })
    };

    return (
        <>
         {(status === "authenticated") ? (
            <div>                
                <h2>Client Component:</h2>
                <p>User Email: {JSON.stringify(session?.user?.email as string, null, 2)}</p>
                <br/>
                <Link href="#" onClick={handleSignOut}>Sign Out</Link>                
            </div>
             ) : ( 
                <><div>
                <p>You are not signed in.</p>
                <Link href="#" onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</Link>                 
              </div></>
             )}
        </>
    );
}

export default ClientComponent;
```

I want to add two links SignIn with Email or SignIn with Username and based on users selection I want to update login_resolution_policy : "Email" in the provider.
I tried passing in signIn() parameter but do not know how to retrieve it in options.ts